# What is the largest prime factor of $55^{100}+55^{101}+55^{102}$

Tags: factoring

Can anyone help me on this?

> What is the largest prime factor of $55^{100}+55^{101}+55^{102}$?

I know $55^{100}+55^{101}+55^{102}=55^{100}*(1+55+55^2)$, but I don't know how to move forward from here.

Comment: @SathasivamK That's neither largest nor prime.

Comment: @robert Israel  you're right

Comment: The answer is 79

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$1+55+55^2 = 3081 = 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 79$.

Answer (score 2):

You can factor out $55^{100}$ from the expression.  The largest prime factor of that number is $11$.

Then it remains to factor $1+55+55^2$, which Prof. Israel did in his answer.